# Change WooCommerce product category title?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo

For SEO purposes I'm trying to change the title (as in: content between `<title></title>` tags) of the product category page of my website.

For example, the product category "Chairs" is now having the title:

"Wooden tables - Myshopname"

I'd like to change this to something else, such as:

"Wooden tables - shop online - Myshopname"

I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin. Can anyone point my towards the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out!

WordPress > Yoast SEO > Titles & meta's > taxonomies

and change "Yoast SEO-metabox" to show under "Product categories".

That'll reveal the Yoast options under the Product Category edit page, allowing you to set titles per category.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution of your query for Yoast SEO plugin:-

Go to the wordpress >> Yoast SEO >> Titles & meta's >> taxonomies and change title template name for Product Categories:

```
   Title template: %%term_title%% %%sep%% shop online %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

Here's my selected separator is "-".

Comment: *Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"...* Well, I respectfully disagree with that indication, kindness is the cornerstone of a community. **Thank you very much**, flawless approach.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to give a different title for different categories

Login to admin panel -> open your site -> category page -> Edit category
Scroll down. In the SEO section add the title for the categories.
do this for all the categories